# Washing machine stops in not-cold program

Tags: washing-machine

We have an old top loader washing machine (model: Privileg maker: Quelle). For a few months we sometimes encounter the problem that the machine stops during the program, exiting with the error code `0 cold` with water still in the machine.

Sadly this error code is not documented, but we guess it has something to do with the heating mechanism since the program get canceled in every program except cold. Single instructions like spinning and pumping are working fine. Since a few days none of the programs works anymore.

What could be the problem? What can we do to fix it? How can we test if the temperature sensor works? I'd like to open the spinning chamber last to check the heating spirals.

---

Update: We measured the heat sensor and bought a new one. Still the same problem. We had a look on the heating spiral - which looked brand new. Now we are searching for errors on the circuit board, maybe a relais is broken. Since the machine does not provide a documented error and we are like the only people facing this concrete problem, we guess it has to be a problem with the circuits.

---

Update: So it seems the relais for water heating was the problem. We exchanged it and the machine runs as expected.

Comment: [tehnomagazin.com/Service-manual/Privileg](https://www.tehnomagazin.com/Service-manual/Privileg.htm) - best I can do; everything else is behind a paywall. Model number?

Comment: @Mazura Thanks. It is a Privileg Dynamic 7811 S.

Comment: [User manual in German](https://manualzz.com/doc/50565806/privileg-873331_20938-benutzerhandbuch) has some phone numbers in it....